# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed", can't create table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How do I resolve this problem? I'm trying to import database into a hosting site, but got this message:
[image]

From this section in the .sql file:
[image]

Comment: What is the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the `wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions` table?

Comment: Don't post images of error messages and table definitions. Create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Was the wp_w_d_p_p table declared first?

Comment: Assuming you're importing complete dump from a functioning system, you may just want to add "set foreign_key_checks=0;" towards the start of the dump file and load the dump.
Of-course beaware of what foreign_key_checks will do! 
Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved by moving the
creation of the table `wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions` before the creation of the table `wp_wc_download_log`